# How to pass a parameter between two jQuery datatables

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have two datatables, one which lists foldes, and another which list's files within their parent folder. Here is how my script looks for the folder table:

```
var oTable = $('#folderTable').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "AJAXViewFolders",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bFilter": false,
            "aoColumns": [
                    { "sName": "folder_id",
                        "bSearchable": false,
                        "bSortable": false,
                        "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                            return '<a href=\"ViewFiles?parentid=' + oObj.aData[0] + '\">View</a>';
                        }
                    },
                    { "sName": "folder_name" },
                    { "sName": "create_date" }
                ]
        });
    });
```

Now, when the user clicks the link I need to be able to pass that parentid to the file datatable. I have had no luck thus far. Here is how the JSON result looks in my controller, for the files datatable:

```
public JsonResult AJAXViewFiles(DataTableParamModel dtParams, int parentid)
    {
        var repo = new TrusteeDocumentRepository();
        var allDocuments = repo.FindAllFiles().Where(c=>c.folder_id == parentid);
        IEnumerable<Files> filteredFiles;
        filteredFiles = allDocuments;


        var displayedFiles = filteredFiles.Skip(dtParams.iDisplayStart).Take(dtParams.iDisplayLength);
        var result = from c in displayedFiles select new[] { Convert.ToString(c.folder_id),c.file_name, c.upload_date.ToString()  };

        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = dtParams.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = allDocuments.Count(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredFiles.Count(),
            aaData = result
        },
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

How would I go about getting the link in the folder table to pass the parentid to the jsonresult for the file's datatable successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the dataTables are on the same page so I'd switch it to a button...

```
"fnRender": function (oObj) {
    return '<button type="button" class="folder-view" data-id="' + oObj.aData[0] + '">View</button>';
}
```

Add a live click handler so you can set the current parentid and refresh the files dataTable. Handler might look like this...

```
$('.folder-view').on('click', function() {
    var $filesTable = $('#filesTable');
    $filesTable.attr('data-parentid', $(this).attr('data-id'));
    //refresh the files table
    $filesTable.dataTable().fnDraw(false);
});
```

Finally, the files dataTable will need to override the `fnServerData` function to merge the extra parentid data...

```
"fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {

    var extraData = [ { parentid: $('#filesTable').attr('data-parentid') } ];

    $.ajax({
        "dataType": "json",
        "type": "POST",
        "url": sSource,
        "data": $.merge(extraData, aoData),
        "success": fnCallback
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. These datatables are on two different pages, but I would assume this solution would work just fine by simply switching out the AJAX url, correct?

Comment: correct, even easier...you could just put the parentid right into the ajax url.